# plot.MCA() not included in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I don't seem to be having a problem with any other method of including a plot via `Sweave`. However, `plot.mca()`, a method from the `FactoMineR` package seems to not have it's plot pulled through. It does create an Rplot.pdf file - but for whatever reason it's not renamed into "RnwFilename-00X.pdf" and not included in the resulting PDF when you `compilePdf()` it in RStudio.

Here's a trivial example, try it for yourself.

Note you may have to: `install.packages("FactoMineR")`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% PREAMBLE
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
<<echo=false,fig=true>>=
library(FactoMineR)
x <- data.frame(
A=sample(letters[1:3],100,rep=T),
B=sample(letters[1:4],100,rep=T),
C=sample(letters[1:3],100,rep=T))
fit.mca <- MCA(x, graph=FALSE)
plot(fit.mca, invisible="ind")
@
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Update - more details on the error message:

```
LaTeX errors:
!pdfTeX error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.EXE (file 
R:/.../RnwFilename-010.pdf): PDF inclusion: required page do
es not exist <0>
```

Comment: If the plot method `plot.fit.mca` is a lattice or ggplot graph then you may need an explicit `print()` around it: this is an Sweave/R FAQ (don't remember the number ...)

Comment: Thanks Ben, that was the first thing I tried, no dice. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if I tell `plot.MCA` not to create a new device:

```
plot(fit.mca, invisible="ind",new.plot = FALSE)
```

Editorializing a bit, this seems like sub-optimal behavior for a plotting function, which most users (and other code, clearly) will expect to rely on R's default action to open a new device automatically. A plot function should only open a new device if the user has explicitly told it to (either by calling `png`, `pdf` etc or by actually setting `new.plot = TRUE`). Opinions may differ on this, though.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I agree completely about the default behavior.

Comment: And that works - and I agree with your op-ed, not at all expected - I read about `new.plot` but had no concept of what it meant.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen The only reason I figured it out was because I tried producing a `pdf` using `pdf()` and `dev.off()` outside of the Sweave document and that _also_ failed, which caused me to look at the code in `plot.MCA` where I discovered the call to `dev.new`. That produced the lightbulb to go off over my head.

Comment: I dropped a note to the package maintainer (Francois Husson) and he's updated the default behaviour to be more inline with what one would intuitively expect.